# parent overlaps child's box-shadow

Tags: css, overflow

I have 2 divs a parent and a child they both have fixed width and the child has fixed height too, child div is floated left and it has `box-shadow:0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4)` the problem is that the parent div overlaps the child's left shadow.

I can't add margin-left to the child because its left side is aligned with the left side of a menu div above the parent div so it has to be exactly where it is.

I tried z-index, minus margin for the parent and so many other things I can't even count but nothing seems to solve the problem.
the code is:

```css
#menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #252525;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
}

#wrapper {
  background: #CCC;
  width: 1195px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  clear: both;
  overflow: auto;
  background: none;
  position: relative;
}

#wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#db_left,
#db_right,
#db_center {
  margin-right: 30px;
  float: left;
}

#db_left {
  width: 170px;
  position: relative;
}

#db_right {
  margin-right: 0 !important;
  width: 315px;
}

#db_center {
  width: 650px;
  margin-top: 20px !important;
}

#profpic_holder {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
      Some Content...
    </div>
    <div id="db_left">
      <div id="profpic_holder">
        <img src="#" width="150" height="150" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div id="profname">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="db_center">
    </div>
    <div id="db_right">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle to demonstrate the problem? When I try your code, the shadow doesn't seem to be cut off, unless I'm misunderstanding the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it.

The `#wrapper` is `overflow:hidden` so nothing outside its area can be seen including the child's shadow.

All I had to do was to hide only the overflow of its top and bottom so I did this:

```
#wrapper{
  overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it

```
 -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 box-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
```

won't have a left shadow. If you want a shadow to show up on all sides use this

```
 -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 box-shadow:0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Because of the 2px blur in the example, there's actually a very slight 1px bit of shadow that's visible on the left and right. Your advice would help if they're looking for a more prominent shadow, though.

Comment: Its not like margin my friend each number has its own job first one moves the shadow horizontally from left to right, the second number moves it vertically, 3rd one is blur size and 4th one is size of the shadow called spread ,, check this link out: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp