# Parent's Overflow:hidden doesn't show child's box-shadow

Tags: html, css

So, I have a react component that returns two divs. The parent div can either be expanded by setting the height to 100% otherwise there's a fixed height.

**Problem is**: The parent has `overflow:hidden`. The child within the parent has a box-shadow. Because `overflow:hidden` it cuts off the child's `box-shadow`, obv, because it counts as an overflow.

**The workaround**: set the child's width to something less than the exact width of the parent and set a margin-bottom. But in the case of page being "left-aligned", meaning there shall be no indents from left this will not work for me. `Overflow-y:hidden;` doesn't work either.

Is there another way to achieve a box-shadow and still use the same logic as mentioned above?

```css
.parent{
  width: 30%;
  max-height: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child{
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of class.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [parent overlaps child's box-shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15249443/parent-overlaps-childs-box-shadow)

Comment: and why you need overflow:hidden?

Comment: @Dharman no, since the correct answer refers to using overflow-y:hidden. And that wont work. Try it yourself in the editor.

Comment: @TemaniAfif, as mentioned above, setting the height to auto or fixed, based on a boolean.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only other alternative would be to expand the parent with negative margins so you can keep your sizing, then apply padding to shrink its content.

If it happens to fall in a container which also has overflow hidden it won't work, though.

```css
.parent{
  width: 30%;
  max-height: 80px;
  margin: -15px;
  padding: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child{
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of class.
  </div>
</div>
```